# Apply string mask

Tags: java, string, masking

I want to apply some kind of **string mask**, I have two Strings, the first one is `final` **"xx"** and the second one may be one letter or two letter String, If it's just one letter (for ex.'**y**' ) I want the resulted String to be **"xy"** and if it consists of two letters (for ex. '**yz**') I  want the resulted String to be **"yz"**, So, it will be like the following:

```
final String a = "xx";
String b = "y";
string c = "yz";
```

by applying the mask to (`a`) and (`b`)

```
String result = "xy"
```

by applying the mask to (`a`) and (`c`)

```
String result = "yz"
```

I know there are a lot of workarounds for that like checking string length, but I'm looking for a strait forward way to achieve that(without using if-else).

Comment: I'd like to know the reason of downvotes

Comment: Perhaps due to the vague problem statement?

Comment: I don't see any vagueness in it, and you already answered the question, so, where is the vagueness? the case is clear, String of one litter or String of two litters.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't think that this was all there is to it, and I almost thought of scrapping my A. (BTW: it's letter; litter == trash) Don't worry about the -1s - there are some strange dudes in the web.

Comment: @laune thanks, and thanks for the "letter" notice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String xx = "xx";
String yz = "yz"; // or "y"
String res = (xx + yz).substring(xx.length()+yz.length() - 2);
```

This will indeed produce "xy" or "yz" but this may be due to your selection of sample data and not work for a more general case you may have had in mind. - If so, make sure to add some explanations to your question.

Otherwise - what's so terrible about an if statement?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a REGEX solution to your problem. Using REGEX, you can check for length and location of your charactors and then act accordingly without resorting to a bunch of if-then-else statements.

Regexs are really easy to test using many online websites. Here is a good example of one:

[regex tester](https://www.regex101.com/)